# How do I set first day of the week to Monday when using Week(Date) in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, date, week-number

I am using the following code to build a Google Chart, to pull in all of entries in a MySQL table corresponding to the Week Numbers in a year.  At the moment the Week Numbers start on a Sunday, and I would like to change this so that they start on a Monday, but I'm not sure how to do this.

```
$i=1;
    while($i<=53)
       {
        $week_start = new DateTime();
        $week_start->setISODate(2013,$i+1);
        $date_display = $week_start->format('j M Y');

        $sessions = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT Sum(Due) from patient_sessions WHERE Type='Session' AND Week(Date)='$i'"));

        $temp = array();

        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date_display); 
        $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $sessions); 
        $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
        $i++;
    }
```

**REVISED CODE**

```
$sessions = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT Due,Date from patient_sessions WHERE Type='Session'"));
$work_times = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT Amount,Date from work_times"));
$expenses = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT Amount,Date from expenses WHERE Client='Psychotherapy'"));

$i=1;
while($i<=53) {
    $week_start = new DateTime();
    $week_start->setISODate(2013,$i+1);
    $date_display = $week_start->format('j M Y');

    $session_total = 0;
    $work_time_total = 0;
    $expense_total = 0;


      foreach ($sessions as $session) {
    if (date("W", strtotime($session->Date)) == $i) {
    $session_total = ($session_total+$session->Due);
    }
    }

         foreach ($work_times as $work_time) {
    if (date("W", strtotime($work_time->Date)) == $i) {
    $work_time_total = ($work_time_total+$work_time->Amount);
    }
    }

          foreach ($expenses as $expense) {
    if (date("W", strtotime($expense->Date)) == $i) {
    $expense_total = ($expense_total+$expense->Amount);
    }
          }

    $balance = ($session_total + $work_time_total - $expense_total);

    $temp = array();

    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $date_display); 
    $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $balance); 
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a hugely inefficient way of doing this! Just grab all the results in one hit and then iterate through the result set.

Comment: @Strawberry You may well be right.  Do you mean use 'SELECT * from patient_sessions' and then use a loop to go through all of the results?  I have noticed that the graphs are slow to load. Presumably this is why?  Is it generally the case that a PHP loop will work faster than using a query in the way I have above?

Comment: Generally (and there are of course exceptions), you want to make as few round trips to the database as possible. Your strategy makes 53 trips. Mine makes 1. However, the issue isn't with "SELECT *". It's with "WHERE Week(Date)='$i'". See GROUP BY.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks - I have added the revised code (after the original code above) that I came up with after receiving your first reply.  It seems more efficient than what I had before, but perhaps could be improved by using GROUP BY.  I wasn't sure if there was a way of combining the 3 foreach statements with the if statements, and I asked a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200661/optimize-iterating-through-array-using-foreach-loops)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
WEEK(date[mode]); 

date = a date value.    
mode = An integer indicating the starting of the week.
```

The default arugment is 0 which is sunday, setting this to 1 will be monday, 2 tuesday and so on.

```
week(date,1);
```

Comment: @gardni "setting this to 1 will be monday, 2 tuesday" isn't true. Per the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), the the start of the week is either Sunday or Monday, the difference is how a week is determined to be part of a year.  Otherwise, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

For it to work in your code, you should be able to change the query to:

```
"SELECT Sum(Due) FROM patient_sessions WHERE Type='Session' AND Week(Date,1)=$i"
```

However, I think I could go one step further and use the GROUP BY to make one sql call, and then iterate over the results;

```
"SELECT Week(Date,1), SUM(DUE) FROM patient_sessions WHERE Type='Session' GROUP BY Week(Date,1)"
```

Alternatively, you might need to use WEEK(Date,2) depending on how you want to handle weeks that span between years.