# MySQL: select date of current week's monday

Tags: mysql

I'm building a weekly report using **MySQL** queries. First I get week number by

```
SELECT WEEK(CURDATE());
```

Then I need to display the starting date of the week (Monday for my region). How to do it with **MySQL** only?

Thanks!

Comment: [`SELECT WEEK(CURDATE(), 1);`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16196958/2451726)

Comment: It works with second parameter omitted as well

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you need date of monday in current week
try this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
```

It return you monday date of current week.

Comment: It works. Using this function we can also get Monday for previous week like this: `SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK)`. Can the latter be written more compact?

Answer (score 12):

In fact, DATE_ADD is not necessary and complicates the logic. Here is the simplest version for "Date of the first day of the current week":

```
select date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day)
```

which would translate to: 
*get the date() part of the (current date - an interval of N days)
where N = today's number in the week, i.e. Thu is number 3 (for a week starting on Monday)*

Then, getting the Monday of previous week, is:

```
select date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day - interval 1 week)
```

which is more readable IMHO.

Comment: In my case, this method had the additional benefit of stripping the time from my TIMESTAMPs.

Comment: You don't need the `date()` wrapper. `curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day` returns a date

Answer (score 4):

For thhose who need the Monday date of the current week.

**If you count Monday as the first day of the week:**

> `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW(), 1),'Monday'), '%x%v %W');`

**If you count Sunday as the first day of the week:**

> `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(YEARWEEK(NOW()),'Monday'), '%X%V %W');`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT curdate() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(curdate())+1)DAY),INTERVAL 1 DAY) as current_monday
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we substruct days, not add them. Just more simple expression:

```
DATE_SUB( CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY( CURDATE() )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-- current week monday
 (SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)) 

-- current week friday  
SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)),INTERVAL 4 DAY);

-- next week monday 
SELECT date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day + interval 1 week);

-- next week friday 
SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT date(curdate() - interval weekday(curdate()) day + interval 1 week)),INTERVAL 4 DAY);
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this:

```
<?php 
    $week = date('W');
    $year = date('Y');
    echo $date1 = date(
        'Y-m-d', 
        strtotime($year . 'W' . str_pad($week, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT))
    );
    ?>
```

Comment: OP asked for a mysql solution not PHP, but thanks anyway as some people might find this helpful